# TSLint member-ordering

Tags: typescript, tslint

I have the following rules in my tslint.json :

```
    "member-ordering": [
        true,
        {
            "order": [
                "public-before-private",
                "static-before-instance",
                "variables-before-functions"
            ]
        }
    ],
```

However I still get this warning :

```
Warning: member-ordering - Bad member kind: public-before-private
```

Typescrypt version is 3.1.1

Node version is 10.10.0

Comment: As the error message says, the values you put in the `order` array are not recognized by `tslint`. Read about `member-ordering` in the [documentation](https://palantir.github.io/tslint/rules/member-ordering/).

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, I'll take some times reading the doc (though I hope that I won't have to reorder the code in my methods and only the tslint.json)

Comment: You can specify in `tslint.json` the exact order you want or you can specify only some components (f.e. let the static methods out) and the missing components can stay anywhere in the class.

Comment: I do know that, however switching from typescrypt 2.9 to 3.1 added these warnings. My bad though, I should have read the documentation more thoroughly

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As the error message says, the values you put in the `order` array are not recognized by tslint. Read about `member-ordering` in the [documentation of the `member-ordering` rule](https://palantir.github.io/tslint/rules/member-ordering/).

You can specify in `tslint.json` the exact order you want or you can specify only some components (f.e. let the static methods out) and the missing components can stay anywhere in the class.

The following configuration matches the rules you expressed:

```
"member-ordering": [
    true,
    {
        "order": [
            "public-static-field",
            "public-static-method",
            "public-instance-field",
            "public-constructor",
            "public-instance-method",

            "protected-static-field",
            "protected-static-method",
            "protected-instance-field",
            "protected-constructor",
            "protected-instance-method",

            "private-static-field",
            "private-static-method",
            "private-instance-field",
            "private-constructor",
            "private-instance-method"
        ]
    }
],
```

Comment: I'll have to do some modifications  on it but thank you very much for your answer, now I know  what I should search.
Thank you for your time